# How can I tell when Chrome extensions are updated?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

In the Chrome browser, there doesn't appear to be any kind of system to show a changelog of updates for extensions.

This seems like basic functionality to let the end user know "Hey, something was updated on `this date` and `here's what was updated`."

How can I tell, or be alerted when a Chrome app or extension has been updated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Extensions Update Notifier](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/extensions-update-notifie/nlldbplhbaopldicmcoogopmkonpebjm?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon).

> **Show a notification when an extension is updated.**
>
> Google Chrome Extensions are auto-updated.
>   This is cool, no doubt about it, but how do you know when an extension is updated?
>
> You don't until you install this extension.
>
> - You will receive a notification when an extension is updated.
> - If the updated extension has a log of records in its Chrome Web Store description, you can view it directly from the extension.
> - And unlike other extensions, it also works with disabled extensions.